# run java program through batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to run my java program through a .bat file. My java program is present in a bin subfolder of the java folder. My batch file is present in the batch folder.

```
cd..
cd java
cd bin
javac screenshot.java
java screenshot
pause
```

The above is the script in my batch file.The program is getting compiled, but while running i am getting:

```
Error:Could not find or load main class screenshot.
```

Can someone tell me where i went wrong? I am stuck.

Comment: screenshot class is on default package?

Comment: Where's the entry point?

Comment: entry point = does the screenshot class have main method?

Comment: yes it has a main method

Comment: The class name while running a program is case sensitive. Verify whether your class name is `screenshot` or `Screenshot` or something of that sort. Also, is the class name `screenshot`? You know, you may have a file with a different name, but the compiled class will have the name of the class declared in the file!

Comment: Provide the source code of your class, please

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your classpath prior to running the Java program. Also, it makes sense to combine the `cd` commands into one:

```
cd ..\java\bin
javac screenshot.java
set CLASSPATH=.
java screenshot
pause
```

Comment: Is your Java program in a package? In other words, does `screenshot.java` have a [package declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html) at the top?

Answer (score 0):

As [inquizitive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120534/inquizitive) pointed out, I made a mistake with the name.
The class name is Screenshot, not screenshot. I am so sorry for troubling you guys.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Maybe that solution will help some people for faster compile their java-programs.

It would be easier if you would make the batch reusable.

```
@echo off                                        
title Java Compiler
:start
cd C:\[...]                                     
set /p id="Enter Name without file extension:"  
javac %id%.java
set /p ic="Enter Name without file extension: "
java %ic%
set /p ib="Want to exit? (type in "exit", else nothing): "
%ib%
set /p ia="Want to Clear the Window? (type in "cls", else nothing): "
%ia%
goto start
```

Line 3 put your project-folder in there, for example "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects"

Line 4 is a new variable, asks you for your source-file. (For the source-file "example.java" type in "example")

Line 5 compile the source file.

Line 6 is another variable, asks for the compiled file.
(For the file "example.class" type in "example")

Line 7 run your compiled java-program.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done in two ways:

a)
  Set JAVA_PATH is in environmental variables.(Right Click->My Computer->Advanced)
  In .bat file please add the following:
     java screenshot
     pause

b) In .bat file do the following entries:
    a) set PATH="%PATH%;%YOUR JAVA PATH TILL BIN%
    b) java screenshot

The above two approaches should work.
If you are setting environment variable please make sure to open a new window.